# how to run multiple commands in ssh linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Im trying to assign echo output to a variable in ssh, but getting below output

`file_temp='/tmp/diskIO_temp.log'`
file_temp contains

> Feb 25 03:06:09 testserver sde
>   Feb 26 03:06:09 testserver sde

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null test@testserver "IFS=$'\n'; cat $file_temp | while read line; do  disk= `echo \$line`; echo \": disk : \$disk :\";done"
```

output:

```
: disk :  :
: disk :  :
```

expected output:

```
Feb 25 03:06:09 testserver sde
Feb 26 03:06:09 testserver sde
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null test@testserver "IFS=$'\n'; file_temp=/tmp/diskIO_temp.log ; cat \$file_temp | while read line; do  disk=\$line ; echo \": disk : \$disk :\";done"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above given code . now it is not even printing : disk :  :
: disk :  :

Comment: where is your `/tmp/diskIO_temp.log` file located ? is it on the remote host ?

Comment: yes it is in remote host. ie testserver
If I run just echo \$line , it gives correct output . But if tries to save the echo\$line to it in a variable it is not working

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code which you gave works fine for but my requirement is different as i want to do the echo $line and assign to variable..
below im mentioning my final requirement
`ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null test@testserver  "IFS=$'\n'; file_temp=/tmp/diskIO_temp.log ; cat \$file_temp | while read line; do  disk=echo \$line | awk {'print \$5'} | grep "25" ; echo \": disk : \$disk :\";done"`
can you please help me with this..